# How to create a table with double line column?

Tags: tables, xetex, line

I want to create following table :

[image]

but I don't know how to achieve those double lines. I tried things like following:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption for the table}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | r |}
  \hline
    Corpus & Tokens \\ \hline \hline
    a & b \\ \hline
    d & e \\ \hline
    f & g \\ \hline \hline
    total & 193,001,930 \\ \hline 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Hint for the future.Please add a minimal working example. With all needed packages. It'll be easier that way.

Comment: *Why* do you want double horizontal lines?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but have you looked at Zarko's addeda?

Comment: Great! Zarko's answer is surely more elegant!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to my taste the the following table is more nice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption for the table}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{ l r }
                            \toprule
    Corpus & Tokens     \\  \midrule
    a & b               \\ 
    d & e               \\  
    f & g               \\  \midrule
    total & 193,001,930 \\  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

If you persist to have table with rules, than `hhline` package enable setting distance between rules in double rule:

```
\setlength\doublerulesep{0.5pt}
```

which gives:

[image]

Complete MWE of above figure is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \setlength\doublerulesep{0.5pt}% <-- set distance between double rule
\caption{Caption for the table}
  \label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | r |}
                            \hline
    Corpus  & Tokens    \\  \hhline{==}
    a       & b         \\  \hline
    d       & e         \\  \hline
    f       & g         \\  \hhline{==}
    total & 193,001,930 \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addedendum (2):**

In case, that you liked the following result:

[image]

than you need only to replace `\hhline{==}` with `\hhline{|==|}` and `\hline` with `\hhline{|--|}.

Comment: With \hhline{|==|} you can have also the external borders, hence my answer is useless!

Comment: ah, i didn't notice, that outer borders are present also at double lines in OP picture ... well this is simple to add :)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a "fake" row of the desidered height, with a `multicolumn` all table long with vertical lines only at its external borders:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.3}%extra vertical spacing between rows
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!] 
        \centering 
        \caption{Caption for the table}\label{tab:table1}
        \begin{tabular}{ | l | r |} 
            \hline 
            Corpus & Tokens \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\[-14pt]% adjust this value according to your needs  
            \hline 
            a & b \\ \hline 
            d & e \\ \hline 
            f & g \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} \\[-14pt]% adjust this value according to your needs 
            \hline 
            total & 193,001,930 \\ \hline 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: from picture showed in OP question I conclude that instead `[-12pt]` the `[-1pt]` is what he looking for :). Interesting idea!

Comment: @Zarko corrected, but with `[-14pt]`...

Comment: Meanwhile I look in `hhline` package and find possibility how to determine distance between lines in double rule. See addendum to my answer. However, your solution is still attractive!

Comment: @Zarko I saw! I've reached my daily voting limit, I'll vote it tomorrow. However, I leave mine because it's different, and there are also the vertical external borders, ciao!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\usepackage{hhline}` and `\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}` (double line space definition).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}

\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption for the table}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{ | l | r |}
  \hline
    Corpus & Tokens \\ \hhline{|=|=|}
    a & b \\ \hline
    d & e \\ \hline
    f & g \\ \hhline{|=|=|}
    total & 193,001,930 \\ \hline 
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

**Update:**
Define line space with ...:.

```
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}
```

(Thanks @Bernard for the comment.)

> Bernard: Just change tge value of \doublerulesep in your preamble: the
>   default in most standard classes is \setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, one more question How can I decrease/increase double line space?

Comment: @Amir: Just change tge value of `\doublerulesep`in your preamble: the default in most standard classes is `\setlength{\doublerulesep}{2pt}`.